# Multiprocessing with specific functions

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

I'm stucking in multiprocessing. My code like this. I want to `func_once()` work on start only. Then other funcitons should work with multiprocessing. But `func_once()` function works parallel and over and over. How can i handle this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

rocket = 0
def func_once():
    print("this func works one.")

func_once()
def func1():
    global rocket
    print ('start func1')
    while rocket < sys.maxsize:
        rocket += 1
    print ('end func1')

def func2():
    global rocket
    print ('start func2')
    while rocket < sys.maxsize:
        rocket += 1
    print ('end func2')

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `map`?

Comment: Try adding `rocket = 0` and call to `func_once()` inside the `__main__` before the processes.

Comment: @Epsi95 `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` is not at all applicable to this problem and it doesn't address the actual issue of `func_once()` being called multiple times. In fact, if you were to create a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance with the default `max_workers` argument, `func_once` would now be called `os.cpu_count()` times.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly running under a platform that does not use an operating system `fork` call to create new processes but rather a `spawn` call. What this means in simple terms is that when you create a new process, each process starts executing from the very top of the program. That is why:

1. The code that launches new processes must be within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. If it weren't, you would get into a recursive loop where the processes you just created would be re-executing the code that creates new processes.
2. The two processes you are creating are each calling `func_once` (poorly named, as we see).

As @anjandash rightly commented, any code at global scope that you do not want to get executed repeatedly by the processes you create should be moved, namely the call to `func_once` (you can leave the function *definition* where it is; it does no real harm there):

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    func_once() # moved to here
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Also, each process has its own memory space and sees its own copy of the declaration `rocket = 0`. That is to say, `func1` and `func2` will *not* be incrementing the same instance of `rocket`.